# Lighting of a scene with a moving camera

Tags: three.js, perspectivecamera, light

```
<html>
    <head>
        ...
    </head>
    <body>
        <script src="three.min.js"></script>
        <script>
            var scene = new THREE.Scene();
            var camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 75, window.innerWidth/window.innerHeight, 0.1, 1000 );

            var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
            renderer.setSize( 600, 400 );
            document.body.appendChild( renderer.domElement );

            var geometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry( 2, 2, 2 );

            var material = new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial( { color: 0xffffff } );
            var material2 = new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial( { color: 0xff007b } );

            var cube = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, material );
            var cube2 = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, material2 );

            cube.position.set(0, 0, 0);
            cube2.position.set(-3, 0, 0);

            scene.add( cube );
            scene.add( cube2 );

            var render = function () {
                requestAnimationFrame( render );
                var directionalLight = new THREE.DirectionalLight( 0xffffff, 0.5 );
                directionalLight.position.set( -3, 3, 3 );
                scene.add( directionalLight );
                var timer = Date.now() * 0.001;
                camera.position.x = Math.cos( timer ) * 10;
                camera.position.z = Math.sin( timer ) * 10;
                camera.lookAt( scene.position );
                renderer.render(scene, camera);
            };

            render();
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

I'm creating cubes and I want them to move in a circle so I move the whole scene in a circle but I have trouble with the lighting because I think it also moves with the scene and when we see the back of the cubes, there's no light. I'm using this library for the first time, so I'm not even sure that I should use directionalLight but I want the cubes closest to the viewer to be lighted and to become darker when they move further from the viewer. Maybe the light should be static and I should not move the camera but I don't know how to do it without moving every cube on its own.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At first, is a bad idea to rotate whole scene. All scene child will be very difficult to imagine for future work.

Create `var space = new Object3D(); scene.add(space); space.add(your_cubes);`

and *rotate* a `space` object instead of `scene`. Put a `light` to the `scene` and set the `space` as a `light.target`.

`light.target = space`;